# cdk versioning errors after upgrading from angular 15 to 17

Tags: angular

I've ugraded my angular application from 15 to 17 following the instructions here:

https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=15.0-17.0

After the upgrade when I attempt npm install, I get the following errors:

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@15.2.3
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@17.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^17.3.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=6.1.0" from @angular-slider/ngx-slider@2.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-slider/ngx-slider
npm ERR!     @angular-slider/ngx-slider@"^2.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   10 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
```

in my package.json I'm seeing:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.1",
```

Comment: You should use the same versions of `@angular/*` packages, so changing `@angular/cdk` to 17.3.1 and reinstalling node_modules should help

Comment: I had similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862870/problem-upgrading-angular-14-to-angular-16-npm-installs-angular-v17-automatical and I ended up modifying package.json manually + delete and reinstall npm modules.

Comment: Thx, updading the package versions manually helped.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use ngx-slider@2.0.4 from @angular/common@">=6.1.0" but in angular v17 you get @angular/common@17.3.1, therefore there is a conflict, try to use slider which supports this version.

Try:

npm install ngx-slider-v2@16.0.0

Comment: ngx-slider-v2 package has been deprecated as per npm (npmjs.com/package/ngx-slider-v2). Please correct the npm install script to use @angular-slider/ngx-slider with v17.

Comment: The the isssue and the error message has nothing to do with the slider.